# reboot issue after solve brightness issue

Tags: grub2, 16.04, laptop, brightness, reboot

I have two problems :

1. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't work on my keyboard to control brightness, so I change `/etc/default/grub` and add `pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=` at the end of `quiet splash` and my problem was solved.
2. After rebooting my laptop, it was freezing during reboot so I added `reboot=acpi` at the end of that phrase but it didn't work for me (when I was adding that at the end of `quiet splash` it works well but after I was adding `pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=` to grub `reboot=acpi` does not work).

Comment: Why adding ```acpi_osi=``` try to ignore that part maybe ?

Comment: `acpi_osi=` is not a valid kernel parameter. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been installed `tlp` and is's not compatible with my laptop (ASUS N552VW) and cause to freeze on restart.

after removing that my problem was solved.

```
 sudo apt purge tlp tlp-rdw
```